# C - Is there a way to remove a mvwprintw from my window? (Ncurses)

Tags: c, ncurses

I want my mvwprintw statement to disappear after a point in the code. I don't know how delete the print statement though. Is there a print function that can do it? I tried by creating another statement full of spaces thinking it would overlap the existing statement and it would look blank. I tried looking online but could not find anything. Please let me know if there is a way.

Comment: "I tried by creating another statement full of spaces thinking it would overlap and it would look blank."  What actually happened?  Can you supply some code to show what you attempted?

Comment: Nothing happend, the previous message was still displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You can clear the whole line by moving to the beginning of a line

```
move(3,0);
```

and then clearing the line

```
clrtoeol();
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a way, hopefully this helps someone with the same problem in the future. All you need to do is to add `\r`at the beginning of your statement and it will over wright anything previously in that spot.

```
mvwprintw(win2,3,16,"Hi.");
mvwprintw(win2,3,16,"\rPlease make your first move."); //overwrites the "Hi"
mvwprintw(win2,3,16,"\rPlease make your second move.");//overwrites the "Please make your first move"
```

Adding blank spaces into the print statement would erase your previous message.

Comment: Does it work properly if you overwrite the last printed text with a smaller sentence?

Comment: No, it will show the remaining of the previous text that is not covered. You can solve this my adding blank spaces to the end of the new sentence. This will cover it all.